# Dark Souls 3: How to press OK?

Tags: pc, dark-souls-3

I'm failing to find a button to remove messages from my sreen.

For example, near Firelink there is a tree, which looks like a giant. You can "Examine" it by pressing "**A**" or it's equivalent for the keyboard, then the message "A seed of the giant is yet to fall" appears, there is "**OK**" button under it.

I can press it with mouse, but I don't like using mouse. I'm failing to see apropriate option in the key settings in the menu. So what button I should press to make such a message disappear? Idealy tell me where I can find the settings for it in the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with other menus in the game, the interact button (default A on controller, E on keyboard) can be used to press the "OK" button.

Comment: I *think* on my game, the "A" button icon is next to the word "OK". I am using a 360 controller.for PC. The OK confirmation does disappear in some circumstances, such as rolling, some dialogs etc. Some of the indicators will change when you move mouse or use keyboard though; I think priority is given to the most recent type of input.

Comment: strange thing, It didn't work before, but now it does. I changed some settings for the menu buttons, to agree them with other settings, for example I used "E" for flask and for Confirm before, now Confirm = "Q" = Interact. May be that was the problem. Whatever... it works.